# Coming from EF to EF Core, how do I use the using statement correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I must be doing something wrong in my context I have my context below which I want to wrap up in my manager class. And I want to be able to use the using statement so that my context is used only once.

```
public class xxxDbContext : DbContext
{
    public xxxDbContext(DbContextOptions<xxxDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<JobsList> JobListingss { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Clients> ClientListings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Engineer> EngineerListing { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Case> CasesListing { get; set; }
}
```

But when I want to use my context in my using statement such as

```
public class xxxContext
{
    xxxDbContext _db = new xxxDbContext();

    public List<Case> GetAllCases(int databaseId)
    {
        List<Case> q = new List<Case>();

        using (var myContext = new xxxDbContext(what must I reference here ?)))
        {
            q = myContext.Cases
                         .Where(w => w.databaseID == databaseId)
                         .OrderBy(o => o.CustomerName).ToList();
        }

        return q;
    }
}
```

Before I was just able to make a parameter less construct can I do same here for core or does that override what is meant to be done.

Also what is best practise should I have a separate class for all these functions or should I have a partial class based on my context?.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [`DbContextoptionsBuilder<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder) generic class to get the instance of options back:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<xxxDbContext>();
```

and now you will have to use the created instance to be passed in the constructor:

```
using (var myContext = new xxxDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options)))
{
  // code here
}
```

**EDIT:**

So what you need is first of all configure a service in services for getting the Options like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // using sqlite as example via official docs example
    services.AddDbContext<xxxDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db"));
}
```

and then in the code where required to create the `dbContext` you could resolve it like:

```
var options = serviceProvider.GetService<DbContextOptions<xxxDbContext>>();
```

and now pass it to the Context class object creation time in constructor:

```
var options = serviceProvider.GetService<DbContextOptions<xxxDbContext>>();
using (var myContext = new xxxDbContext(options)))
{
  // code here
}
```

You can refer to the following post for details at official docs:

[Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder-1)

Comment: Two things: you have to pass `builder.Options` and passing an empty configuration will only give you problems

Comment: agreed on first point, for second one i referred to the official docs to go through how it needs to be configured

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks ethan dont no why it was mark down as was asking how do you do this in core

Comment: I wasnt wanting to pass anything empty @CamiloTerevinto I was asking what was correct way of doing it in core.

Comment: @DavidB yes, that' what my understanding was from the question